# Set div background in jQuery ajax success from an image response

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a controller action that I am going to request. The response is as follows.

```
return send_file(@image_path,
  :disposition => 'inline',
  :filename => @image.title,
  :type => @image.content_type)
```

What I want to achieve is, in my ajax success function, I would like to call a div and set its background to this response image. How can I achieve this.

My jquery ajax code is

```
jQuery.get('url(:open_image, :id => 'someID' )}').
  success(function(data, status, xhr) {
    jQuery("#my_id").css('background-image', 'url(' + data + ')');
})
```

This is not working for me, don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: You need to share the AJAX call that does that, instead of showing the ruby code, because your question deals with client side and not server side. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar I have edited the code to add the ajax code.

Comment: Where have you defined the `elementId`?

Comment: Edited with the actual ID.

Comment: Does it work then? What actually the `data` contains? Put `console.log(data)` after the `jQuery("#my_id").css('background-image', 'url(' + data + ')');` line and see what `data` is coming?

Comment: There's the image data I can see it, too big to put it here :)

Comment: Oh, so you are sure that it is a data URL? Can you put a first few bytes of it?

Comment: �PNG


IHDR���Y
$ IDATx^ܽ ��u&��YYwuU�h4��8�(��E�m��m�س^{�ؙ��h7b����ֳ#�!{tٖ�ے(Z� J"@�$��@�/�]]w޹�����ή�������UY������w����E,ۦM_�ï~�8�+�~�������F���{� ������9�[��{���y���w�-��ы>�x���q��W���˻�m��>������7���-��7����7�
�`���h�y^�0'���!�+Zks�l�����{�l�|Z�G�|DZ����VȲp��
ެ�Z���狼��f�:�|}M��{ú�A�������wo�����>˿��������;��_�'(��[[������v�ύ�_�[ ޸��'p��g���:�.O�������k_������9��x�Y����6[K�gq��ϳ����Ml2A`�i��j�H-��d���ol]7��u��ﳮ}��Q�8��*��w�OƯ�.�(2��|����eD�{�����6�tS��ͮ�,k�����~��@؂n�D4��޵~�m4��U`µ~_

Comment: I got the issue. Lemme show what to do.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: Don't know how to put that code in my ruby controller couldn't try that.
I am using send_file...

Comment: Ah... I don't know Ruby buddy.

Comment: This helped me achieve what I wanted
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676698/pass-parameters-to-xmlhttprequest-object

Answer (score 1):

Try putting something like this in your onSuccess method

```
$('myOjbect').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a base64 encoded output in you PHP:

```
base64_encode($output);
```

In your CSS, do this:

```
jQuery("#my_id").css('background-image', 'url("data:image/png;base64,' + data + ')');
```